# How to cover gap below garage back door

Tags: insulation, garage, weatherstripping

I have a 3/4" gap between my garage back door (see image. blueish color is outside evening light).
Looking for a good way to cover this gap with two goals in mind:

- Stop rodents from coming in
- Help as much as possible to keep heat from escaping

The door is a simple wooden door. The floor is cement.
I know there are some thick rubber bands that can be used. Are there any better solutions?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution will be to install a larger door sweep on the inside. Sweeps come in a variety of sizes and styles. Check the out at any home improvement store. They easily attach to the door with a few screws and are adjustable so you can be sure they gently touch the floor and solve your gap problem